# Why would a Google Cloud instance tag drop packets?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-vpn

I have a VPC with two Compute Engine VM instances in it. One of them, `vpn-server`, is acting as a VPN for a cluster of on-premises computers. The other, `test-instance`, is configured with an instance tag `route-through-vpn` that routes traffic to the `vpn-server` if it's going to `10.10.0.0/19`.

There is also an AppEngine instance that has the `route-through-vpn` instance tag. The webapp running in it can directly connect to our on-premises cluster.

This setup has worked just fine for over a year. Then yesterday, a small number of IP addresses suddenly stopped working.

By "stopped working" I mean this:

- It is still possible to SSH into the non-working IP addresses if you're logged into the `vpn-server`.
- But traffic originating from `test-instance` cannot reach these IPs.

One of the failing IPs is `10.10.0.8`. One IP that still works is `10.10.0.47`. As far as I can tell, all addresses correctly match the address range `10.10.0.0/19`.

To debug, I logged into the `vpn-server` and the `test-instance` and tried sending ICMP packets from `test-instance` to various IP addresses in the cluster. I also ran `tcpdump` on the `vpn-server` so I could see the traffic as it passed through.

For the IP addresses that are still working, I saw the ICMP packets in the output of `tcpdump`, as expected. But for the IP addresses that are no longer working, I see nothing in `tcpdump`, indicating that Gcloud's routing layer is not even sending the traffic to my `vpn-server`.

To test further, I shut down one of the on-premises machines whose traffic is being routed properly, and I tried pinging it. The ICMP echo request packets appeared in the output of `tcpdump` with no replies, exactly as expected.

Google Cloud's routes don't have a whole lot of options, and there's no information available that would help me investigate further, so now it's down to somebody just happening to know why this would happen.

Has anybody solved a problem like this or have any idea what might be the cause?

Comment: If you enable VPC Flow Logs, that will give you insight into what's happening on the network.

Comment: I got flow logs turned on for all my subnets, and it collected a lot of data. I made some test connections while flow logs were on. But none of the data in the log matched the IP address or VM name of my `test-instance` at all.

Answer (score -1):

It seems more like an instance configuration or routing table issue, If I understood correctly, the IP address 10.10.x.x/19 are from your on-Prem. We can discard firewall rules since I'm supposing that you have a rule similar to "allow ingress/egress traffic from the source / destination 10.10.0.0 /19" and if you're seeing that the IP address 10.10.0.47 still works, means that the firewall rule is working, seems more that a routing behavior, have you tried to clean your route table inside your instance? It can help to refresh your routing table. I know that GCP has an option where you can use an [instance as gateway](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/special-configurations#settingupvpn) It sounds similar to what you are doing.